# How to update the null column?

Tags: ms-access

Using Access 2003

Two Table, Tmp_cardevent1, tmp_cardevent3

Query

```
SELECT AllPossibleCardEvents.PersonId,  AllPossibleCardEvents.CardEventDate, Actual.Intime FROM ((SELECT p.PersonId,  AllDates.CardEventDate FROM (SELECT DISTINCT CardEventDate FROM TMP_Cardevent3) AllDates, Tmp_cardevent1  p) AllPossibleCardEvents LEFT OUTER JOIN TMP_cardevent3  Actual ON AllPossibleCardEvents.PersonId = Actual.PersonId AND AllPossibleCardEvents.CardEventDate = Actual.CardEventDate)
```

Output.

```
PERSONID    CardEventDate   Intime
3156    05/08/2008  
3335    05/08/2008  
3405    05/08/2008  20:58:58
3406    05/08/2008  
3410    05/08/2008  
3422    05/08/2008  
3424    05/08/2008  
3441    05/08/2008  
3447    05/08/2008  
3461    05/08/2008  
48  05/08/2008  
484 05/08/2008  
5   05/08/2008  
5008    05/08/2008  20:01:45
```

So on…,

For the Blank Intime column I want to display like this ‘-----‘

Tried Query

```
SELECT PERSONID, CARDEVENTDATE, INTIME FROM
(SELECT AllPossibleCardEvents.PersonId, AllPossibleCardEvents.CardEventDate, (iif(Actual.Intime=’’, ‘-----‘,Actual.Intime) as Intime FROM ((SELECT p.PersonId,  AllDates.CardEventDate FROM (SELECT DISTINCT CardEventDate FROM TMP_Cardevent3) AllDates, Tmp_cardevent1  p) AllPossibleCardEvents LEFT OUTER JOIN TMP_cardevent3  Actual ON AllPossibleCardEvents.PersonId = Actual.PersonId AND AllPossibleCardEvents.CardEventDate = Actual.CardEventDate) )
```

But I cannot able to update the null column, Is the structure is available for the Intime column

Expected Output

```
PERSONID    CardEventDate   Intime
3156    05/08/2008  -----
3335    05/08/2008  -----
3405    05/08/2008  20:58:58
3406    05/08/2008  -----
3410    05/08/2008  -----
3422    05/08/2008  -----
3424    05/08/2008  -----
3441    05/08/2008  -----
3447    05/08/2008  -----
3461    05/08/2008  -----
48  05/08/2008  -----
484 05/08/2008  -----
5   05/08/2008  -----
5008    05/08/2008  20:01:45
```

How to make a query for this null column?

Comment: Please make more effort to format your code in to a more readable state

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [IsNull](http://www.techonthenet.com/access/functions/advanced/isnull.php) built-in function.

```
SELECT
    PERSONID,
    CARDEVENTDATE,
    INTIME
FROM
    (SELECT
        AllPossibleCardEvents.PersonId,
        AllPossibleCardEvents.CardEventDate,
        (iif(iif(IsNull(Actual.Intime), '', Actual.Intime)='', '-----', Actual.Intime) as Intime
    FROM ((SELECT
        p.PersonId,
        AllDates.CardEventDate FROM
        (SELECT DISTINCT
            CardEventDate FROM TMP_Cardevent3) AllDates,
            Tmp_cardevent1  p) AllPossibleCardEvents
        LEFT OUTER JOIN TMP_cardevent3 Actual
        ON AllPossibleCardEvents.PersonId = Actual.PersonId AND
        AllPossibleCardEvents.CardEventDate = Actual.CardEventDate))
```

Comment: Why not simply: iif(Actual.Intime IS NULL, '-----', Actual.Intime) as Intime; Also, considering the column will be coerced to NVARCHAR(255) wouldn't it be a good idea to explicitly format the DATETIME e.g. iif(Actual.Intime IS NULL, '-----', FORMAT$(Actual.Intime, 'hh:nn:ss')) as Intime; ?

Comment: This will only convert the `NULL` values to dashes, he also wants to convert empty strings to dashes. By the way we can also use the `IS NULL` check.

Comment: Why not Nz? Nz(Actual.Intime,"") or better: Trim(Actual.Intime & "")=""